# How can I change http to https in an svg header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Am wondering how can we replace http url in svg file header with https

i tried like this but no success.

**html**

```
<svg class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <path
        d="M 50.0625 10.4375 C 48.214844 11.257813 46.234375 11.808594 44.152344 12.058594 C 46.277344 10.785156 47.910156 8.769531 48.675781 6.371094 C 46.691406 7.546875 44.484375 8.402344 42.144531 8.863281 C 40.269531 6.863281 37.597656 5.617188 34.640625 5.617188 C 28.960938 5.617188 24.355469 10.21875 24.355469 15.898438 C 24.355469 16.703125 24.449219 17.488281 24.625 18.242188 C 16.078125 17.8125 8.503906 13.71875 3.429688 7.496094 C 2.542969 9.019531 2.039063 10.785156 2.039063 12.667969 C 2.039063 16.234375 3.851563 19.382813 6.613281 21.230469 C 4.925781 21.175781 3.339844 20.710938 1.953125 19.941406 C 1.953125 19.984375 1.953125 20.027344 1.953125 20.070313 C 1.953125 25.054688 5.5 29.207031 10.199219 30.15625 C 9.339844 30.390625 8.429688 30.515625 7.492188 30.515625 C 6.828125 30.515625 6.183594 30.453125 5.554688 30.328125 C 6.867188 34.410156 10.664063 37.390625 15.160156 37.472656 C 11.644531 40.230469 7.210938 41.871094 2.390625 41.871094 C 1.558594 41.871094 0.742188 41.824219 -0.0585938 41.726563 C 4.488281 44.648438 9.894531 46.347656 15.703125 46.347656 C 34.617188 46.347656 44.960938 30.679688 44.960938 17.09375 C 44.960938 16.648438 44.949219 16.199219 44.933594 15.761719 C 46.941406 14.3125 48.683594 12.5 50.0625 10.4375 Z "
    ></path>
</svg>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('svg [xmlns="http://"]').each(function () {
        var oldUrl = jQuery(this).attr("xmlns");
        console.log(oldUrl);
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("http://", "https://");
        jQuery(this).attr("xmlns", newUrl);
    });
});
```

**snippet**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('svg [xmlns="http://"]').each(function () {
        var oldUrl = jQuery(this).attr("xmlns");
        console.log(oldUrl);
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("http://", "https://");
        jQuery(this).attr("xmlns", newUrl);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <path
        d="M 50.0625 10.4375 C 48.214844 11.257813 46.234375 11.808594 44.152344 12.058594 C 46.277344 10.785156 47.910156 8.769531 48.675781 6.371094 C 46.691406 7.546875 44.484375 8.402344 42.144531 8.863281 C 40.269531 6.863281 37.597656 5.617188 34.640625 5.617188 C 28.960938 5.617188 24.355469 10.21875 24.355469 15.898438 C 24.355469 16.703125 24.449219 17.488281 24.625 18.242188 C 16.078125 17.8125 8.503906 13.71875 3.429688 7.496094 C 2.542969 9.019531 2.039063 10.785156 2.039063 12.667969 C 2.039063 16.234375 3.851563 19.382813 6.613281 21.230469 C 4.925781 21.175781 3.339844 20.710938 1.953125 19.941406 C 1.953125 19.984375 1.953125 20.027344 1.953125 20.070313 C 1.953125 25.054688 5.5 29.207031 10.199219 30.15625 C 9.339844 30.390625 8.429688 30.515625 7.492188 30.515625 C 6.828125 30.515625 6.183594 30.453125 5.554688 30.328125 C 6.867188 34.410156 10.664063 37.390625 15.160156 37.472656 C 11.644531 40.230469 7.210938 41.871094 2.390625 41.871094 C 1.558594 41.871094 0.742188 41.824219 -0.0585938 41.726563 C 4.488281 44.648438 9.894531 46.347656 15.703125 46.347656 C 34.617188 46.347656 44.960938 30.679688 44.960938 17.09375 C 44.960938 16.648438 44.949219 16.199219 44.933594 15.761719 C 46.941406 14.3125 48.683594 12.5 50.0625 10.4375 Z "
    ></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: For one thing your selector is looking for a descendant of the SVG element due to the space after `svg`, but the attribute is _on_ that element.

Comment: For another, you don't have any elements with exactly that value. You need a _starts with_ selector (`^=`).

Comment: You really shouldn't change the namespace on your svgs. It technically makes them invalid even though browsers might be able to display them. Check https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/738 for more info.

Comment: I am a huge fan of svg and reading your question I was wondering why do you need to do so? Just to improve my knowlegde.

Comment: Could some one please can explain me why and what is it needed for?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren thanks for the point , its one of my client requested that some SEO company told him to change svg http to https .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the selector from `svg [xmlns="http://"]` to `svg`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("svg").each(function () {
        var oldUrl = jQuery(this).attr("xmlns");
        console.log(oldUrl);
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("http://", "https://");
        jQuery(this).attr("xmlns", newUrl);
        console.log(newUrl);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <path
        d="M 50.0625 10.4375 C 48.214844 11.257813 46.234375 11.808594 44.152344 12.058594 C 46.277344 10.785156 47.910156 8.769531 48.675781 6.371094 C 46.691406 7.546875 44.484375 8.402344 42.144531 8.863281 C 40.269531 6.863281 37.597656 5.617188 34.640625 5.617188 C 28.960938 5.617188 24.355469 10.21875 24.355469 15.898438 C 24.355469 16.703125 24.449219 17.488281 24.625 18.242188 C 16.078125 17.8125 8.503906 13.71875 3.429688 7.496094 C 2.542969 9.019531 2.039063 10.785156 2.039063 12.667969 C 2.039063 16.234375 3.851563 19.382813 6.613281 21.230469 C 4.925781 21.175781 3.339844 20.710938 1.953125 19.941406 C 1.953125 19.984375 1.953125 20.027344 1.953125 20.070313 C 1.953125 25.054688 5.5 29.207031 10.199219 30.15625 C 9.339844 30.390625 8.429688 30.515625 7.492188 30.515625 C 6.828125 30.515625 6.183594 30.453125 5.554688 30.328125 C 6.867188 34.410156 10.664063 37.390625 15.160156 37.472656 C 11.644531 40.230469 7.210938 41.871094 2.390625 41.871094 C 1.558594 41.871094 0.742188 41.824219 -0.0585938 41.726563 C 4.488281 44.648438 9.894531 46.347656 15.703125 46.347656 C 34.617188 46.347656 44.960938 30.679688 44.960938 17.09375 C 44.960938 16.648438 44.949219 16.199219 44.933594 15.761719 C 46.941406 14.3125 48.683594 12.5 50.0625 10.4375 Z "
    ></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS doesn't handle XML namespaces directly. Try this:

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('svg').each(function () {
      var oldUrl = jQuery(this).attr("xmlns");
      console.log(oldUrl);
      if (oldUrl) {
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("http://", "https://");
        jQuery(this).attr("xmlns", newUrl);
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
   <path d="M 50.0625 10.4375 C 48.214844 11.257813 46.234375 11.808594 44.152344 12.058594 C 46.277344 10.785156 47.910156 8.769531 48.675781 6.371094 C 46.691406 7.546875 44.484375 8.402344 42.144531 8.863281 C 40.269531 6.863281 37.597656 5.617188 34.640625 5.617188 C 28.960938 5.617188 24.355469 10.21875 24.355469 15.898438 C 24.355469 16.703125 24.449219 17.488281 24.625 18.242188 C 16.078125 17.8125 8.503906 13.71875 3.429688 7.496094 C 2.542969 9.019531 2.039063 10.785156 2.039063 12.667969 C 2.039063 16.234375 3.851563 19.382813 6.613281 21.230469 C 4.925781 21.175781 3.339844 20.710938 1.953125 19.941406 C 1.953125 19.984375 1.953125 20.027344 1.953125 20.070313 C 1.953125 25.054688 5.5 29.207031 10.199219 30.15625 C 9.339844 30.390625 8.429688 30.515625 7.492188 30.515625 C 6.828125 30.515625 6.183594 30.453125 5.554688 30.328125 C 6.867188 34.410156 10.664063 37.390625 15.160156 37.472656 C 11.644531 40.230469 7.210938 41.871094 2.390625 41.871094 C 1.558594 41.871094 0.742188 41.824219 -0.0585938 41.726563 C 4.488281 44.648438 9.894531 46.347656 15.703125 46.347656 C 34.617188 46.347656 44.960938 30.679688 44.960938 17.09375 C 44.960938 16.648438 44.949219 16.199219 44.933594 15.761719 C 46.941406 14.3125 48.683594 12.5 50.0625 10.4375 Z "></path>
</svg>
```